# Calling function in javascript Google API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, heatmap, google-geocoder

I am using Google JavaScript API with geocoding and heatmap. But I am having some trouble.
Here is my script:

content of coords.js:

```
eqfeed_callback()
```

My question is, why I can not call the function `heatMapVisualize()` anywhere else except the eqfeed_callback function. When I put the function call of `heatMapVisualize()` somewhere else, it will not do it. How ever the eqfeed_callback is empty.

My second question which is depending on the first one. How can I get rid of this function theese lines:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://www.stud.fit.vutbr.cz/~xhalin01/BP/coords.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

I dont need them anymore. There I used to store the locations for heatmapdata, but now I do it via Google Geocoder. I am new to Javascript so excuse my dumb question But I will put bounty on this.

Comment: Your edit makes your question much less clear to me.

Comment: Meanwhile I assumed I do not need that. I wanted to delete this, but I could not because there is comment. I put flag on this instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you call it outside the callback the variables used WITHIN that function are only initialized to the defaults set at the top of your script - basically nothing/empty - undefined and empty array.

Put that `script` in as a tag ABOVE the others with `src=` attribute set.

Comment: I do not really understand since I have not many experience in javascript. Why I should keep that eqfeed_callback when I dont use it anymore. I dont use that file coords.js

Comment: So just remove those lines?  You can remove anything and not impact your code if it is not used.